# If you were to design a PKI from scratch, what would you do?

Tags: pki

In what ways would you simplify?  What would be changed to be more modern or extensible?  Suppose you have no requirement to adapt to previous protocols.  Links to proposed designs, existing protocols, as well as any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Personally, I'd include [something like](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/833.pdf) [CONIKS](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/1004.pdf) from the start on. Otherwise default to something like Ed448 and Curve448, use AES and prepare yourself for the rise of quantum computers.

Comment: BTW.: This question may be waaaaay to broad and Crypto.SE is no disuscussion forum but rather a Question & Answer site. You may want to break your question down into smaller parts for receiving better answers.